# Angular Dart build fails after upgrade Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I keep getting below error after I upgrade my Dart SDK. It seems [webdev](https://pub.dev/packages/webdev#206) package has been upgraded from version 2.0.5 to 2.0.6. However I can't run my project now,

```
"G:\Program Files\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat" global run webdev build --output=web:build
webdev could not run for this project.
This version of webdev does not support the `build_daemon` protocol used by your version of `build_runner`.
Please add a dev dependency on `build_daemon` with constraint: >=1.0.0 <2.0.0
Process finished with exit code 78
```

I tried by following error messages hints but couldn't help!

And then, I generate a new project using Dart's project generator called [stagehand](https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand), same there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through this last night.  Had to deactivate webdev

```
pub global deactivate webdev
```

Then activate with a specific version (2.0.1 in my case)

```
pub global activate webdev 2.0.1
```

I didn't try a different version as 2.0.1 was giving success and I wanted to get through completing my sample app.  There are some interesting reads about how 2.0.6 was supposed to fix some things, but it's requiring build_daemon version 1 whereas the default Angular dart sample I was using was requiring 0.5.0.

Comment: Subscribe to this issue if you're curious when it gets resolved.  https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/408

Comment: Sure I'll add a comment there

Comment: Looks like the fix worked they put in Angular Dart 5.3.1.  Had to bump build_runner to 1.5.0